# Replace spaces between two strings with symbol using sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have string like this:

```
20.07.2010|Berlin|id 100|bd-22.10.94|Marry Scott Robinson|msc@gmail.com
```

I need to replace whitespaces *only* between "Marry Scott Robinson" with "|". So to have `bd-22.10.94|Marry|Scott|Robinson|`

There many of such rows, so problem is in replace whitespace only between "bd-" and vertical line after name.

Comment: Please share the command that does not work for you, and any attempt to fix it for us to see what problem you are having.

Comment: Problem is in ranging sed and my level. I know how to replace whitespaces. It can be done using grep or awk, separately, but here it should be done only using sed. Maybe awk with split instead of sed should work :/

Comment: What is the regex you tried to match the block? Is it important to match `bd-`  in specific context only? Can there be any chars after `bd-`, not just numbers and dots? `sed` can easily do what you need, but it is not quite clear what that block must look like. That is why your current command would be of much help.

Comment: If you have a GNU sed, you may even use a regex like `\(.*\)\(bd-[^|]*|[^|]*\)\(.*\)` to get the substring you need and then pass the `e` modifier with appropriate RHS to replace each space with `|` in the second group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume that the name is always on the fifth column :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{gsub(/ /,OFS,$5)}1' file
```

If it is not the case, you can do :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /bd-/){break}};gsub(/ /,OFS,$(i+1))}1' file
```

Returns :

```
20.07.2010|Berlin|id 100|bd-22.10.94|Marry|Scott|Robinson|msc@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lne '($before, $change, $after) = /(.*\|bd-.*?\|)(.*?)(\|.*)/;
           print $before, $change =~ s/ /|/gr, $after' -- file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line, running the code for each line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output
- the first line populates three variables by values captured from the line. `$before` contains verything up to the first `|` after `bd-`; `$change` contains what follows up to the next `|`, and `$after` contains the rest.
- `s/ /|/gr` replaces spaces by pipes (`/g` for "all of them") and returns (`/r`) the result.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^|]*/\n&\n/5;:a;s/\(\n[^\n ]*\) /\1\|/;ta;s/\n//g' file
```

Sometimes to fix a problem we must erect scaffolding, then fix the original problem and finally remove the scaffolding.

Here we need to isolate the field by surrounding it by newlines.

Remove the spaces between the newlines by looping until failure.

Finally, remove the scaffolding i.e. the introduced newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Another perl version:

```
$ perl -F'\|' -ne '$F[4] =~ tr/ /|/; print join("|", @F)' foo.txt
20.07.2010|Berlin|id 100|bd-22.10.94|Marry|Scott|Robinson|msc@gmail.com
```

Same basic idea as Corentin's first awk example. Split each line into columns based on `|`, replace spaces in the 5th one with `|`'s, print the re-joined lines.